# how to make windows recognise only one USB?

Tags: windows, usb, security

I wanted to do a windows system to recognize and work only with my usb not others, is that possible?
Does any one know how to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SU. What do you mean by USB? Socket, Bus, Device?

Comment: Hi Thank U for the reply.
I mean I want to use a single USB device that every time I put my USB the system recognizes it. If someone else put their own usb I don't want them to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent installations of removable drives completelly and add your devices as exceptions.

It can be configured from:

`Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Device Installation -> Device Installation Restrictions`

You can follow this official Microsoft [manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530324.aspx)

[specifically this part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530324.aspx#grouppolicydeviceinstall_topic6)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that if you have physical access to the device, this will not help. If you can access the BIOS and boot another OS for example, you'll have full access to the disk and everything on it. I really think the question needs to be clarified with a *goal* to give a good answer.

Comment: I agree, if this is really a question of security, one can easily perform a usb boot and there is not much you can do about it even with  a BIOS password. _save for physically blocking usb hubs_

Comment: Hi Thank U for the reply. I mean I want to use a single USB device that every time I put my USB the system recognizes it. If someone else put their own usb I don't want them to work. 
I used this option with my domain GPO but the system if a user waits and doesnt close the administrator prompt windows can open the device and transfere material to it.